# docker + dotnet watch

Tags: .net, docker, watch

I use Visual studio Code.

I create a new projet dotnet new webapi. I have referenced dotnet-watch in my .csproj :
    `<ItemGroup>
        <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
        <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
        <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlConfig.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>`

Then, I Build my DockerFile.

I notice strange behavior. The docker image detects the changes and rebuilds the solution. The binary files have been updated in bin and obj directory but when I call the api, it is as if there had never been any change.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5000
EXPOSE 5000

ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

Docker command : docker run -i -p 5000:5000 -v $(pwd):/app -t docker-todoapi

finally in the container terminal : docker restore and docker Watch run

Comment: Can you run docker images and see what all tags you have for that image? It may not be tagging the builds as "latest"

Answer (score 1):

This blog post describes the current issues, but also how to get around the issues:

http://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/11/13/dotnet-watch-and-docker/

To summarize changes you need:

Use version **2.1.0-preview1-27567** of **Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools**.

To get this preview version you need to add a NuGet.config file to your project directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="aspnetcore-nightly" value="https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-dev/api/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

The `bin` and `obj` directories used in Docker must be separated from those used by Visual Studio Code, or you will have the problems you are currently seeing.

To do this the `bin` and `obj` directories must be placed in a rather odd place outside of the project directory, which can be accomplished by adding a file called `Directory.Build.props` to your project directory:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/../obj/</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <BaseOutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/../bin/</BaseOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

You must also delete the old `bin` and `obj` directories from your project directory.